# Can I have a list of software to run a two nodes HA Ubuntu (server) cluster?

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, high-availability

This is only for experimental purpose :-) I want to learn how to create a High-Availability Ubuntu (server) cluster. What are the basic software requirements? I heard about Beowoulf, heartbeat and other strange words but I'm not sure... I only need a list of recommended software so I can learn the rest by myself :-)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Linux HA is good... I have tried it for basic clustering both in the case of mysql as well as web server and it works fine..

Well you can use this link to configure in case of httpd

http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/linux/heartbeat-2-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu [supports](http://fghaas.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/ubuntu-10-04-with-full-cluster-stack-support/) the [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/) cluster resource manager and the [Corosync](http://www.corosync.org/doku.php) cluster messaging layer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to implement. Generally speaking you can have a look at the Linux-HA suite and its subprojects: http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page

What is what you have in mind?

Comment: The Linux-HA project has basically morphed/spawned Pacemaker which can now be coupled with Heartbeat (also from Linux-HA) or Corosync (previously OpenAIS) as the messaging layer. See http://clusterlabs.org for the latest software and information.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions! I want install any kind of server software on the first node and have it automatically replicated on the second node so that if the first node goes down the second takes immediately place. Something like a Raid-over-network :-)

Comment: You can also have a look at DRBD (kind of network-based RAID 1).

Comment: Theank you Alvaro! DRBD looks interesting!